# Couchbase 4 beta "ORDER BY" performance

Tags: couchbase, sql++, nosql

I have one question about performance of "ORDER BY" in Couchbase 4 Beta (Ubuntu 64bits).

I create a Bucket "testing" and a primary index:

```
CREATE PRIMARY INDEX `testing-idx` ON `testing` USING GSI;
```

And a second index:

```
CREATE INDEX testing_field_value_idx ON `testing`(field_value) USING GSI
```

In my bucket I have items such as:

```
{
  "type": "entry",
  "field_name": "field-testing",
  "field_value": "1 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla"
},
{
  "type": "entry",
  "field_name": "field-testing",
  "field_value": "2 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla"
},
{
  "type": "entry",
  "field_name": "field-testing",
  "field_value": "3 bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla"
}
...
```

When I execute the query without ORDER BY the response is fast (milliseconds):

```
SELECT field_value FROM testing LIMIT 10;

1.000 items: 53 ms
100.000 items: 82 ms
```

But when I execute the query with ORDER BY, the response is slow (seconds):

```
SELECT field_value FROM testing ORDER BY field_value ASC LIMIT 10;

1.000 items: 4.6 secs
100.000 items: 6.2 secs
```

How to get better performance with ORDER BY?

** All the queries are executed in "cbq".

Comment: How many total items are in your bucket?

Comment: @geraldss Exactly 1000 in the first and 100000 in the second test. Any idea?

Comment: Yes, we know the issue and will fix it. In the case of your specific query, we should avoid fetching the documents after scanning the index. You can go ahead and build your app, and you will transparently pick up the performance speed up when we fix it.

Comment: Hi @geraldss please any news about this issue? I Installed "Couchbase Server 4.0 Release Candidate" and is one second better (3.5 secs in the same query with ORDER BY) but 3.5 seconds is not a good time I think. Thank you.

Comment: @rafaelsouzaf Please any update on this issue? I am still facing this issue with stable Couchbase 4.

Comment: @geraldss "Yes, we know the issue and will fix it. " - any open defect number/link to track it?

Comment: @JahanzaibAslam unfortunately not. No news about this.

Comment: Fixed by http://review.couchbase.org/#/c/57495/ This fix will be available in the next release. And actually, your query will already benefit from the covering indexes in 4.1, which has already been released. The next release will include a further optimization of ORDER BY with LIMIT.

Comment: I got same issue on 4.5.0-2601 @geraldss: is this a bug also ?

Comment: What is the issue on 4.5? Please open a separate Stack Overflow topic.