# Couchbase 4 “ORDER BY” performance in Stable Version

Tags: couchbase, sql++

**DUPLICATE:** [Couchbase 4 beta “ORDER BY” performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30670366/couchbase-4-beta-order-by-performance)

Like Question title shows, I am facing huge response delay like 13s for one call using Couchbase 4 (N1QL) `ORDER BY` clause. If I don't use `ORDER BY` clause every thing is fine.

My Primary Index is

```
Definition: CREATE PRIMARY INDEX `#primary` ON `default` USING GSI
```

and secondary index is

```
Definition: CREATE INDEX `index_location_name` ON `default`(`name`) USING GSI
```

N1QL Query

`req.params.filter` can be any key in the location document.

> SELECT _id AS id FROM default WHERE type = 'location' ORDER BY " +
>   req.params.filter + (req.query.descending?' DESC':'') + " LIMIT " +
>   limit + " OFFSET " + skip

Location Document in my Bucket is

```
{
  "_id": "location::370794",
  "name": "Kenai Riverside Fishing",
  "avgRating": 0,
  "city": "Cooper Landing",
  "state": "Alaska",
  "country": "USA",
  "zipCode": "99572",
  "created": "2013-07-10T17:30:00.000Z",
  "lastModified": "2015-02-13T12:34:36.923Z",
  "type": "location",
}
```

Any one can tell why `ORDER BY` clause is making so much delay?

Comment: Can you post the metrics at the end of your result, including sortCount.

Comment: In addition, please post the explain plan. I have to think you have no index on type in your WHERE clause and therefor the query will be really slow.

For the order by performing poorly, that is dependent on RAM and CPU on the node(s) running the query service. So check these resources. Also, why are you testing on the beta? At least test on 4.0. If you are considering buying the enterprise version, 4.1 had some great performance improvements that are not in the community versions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe couchbase is not built to handle queries that can be ordered by any field. Since, ordering is an expensive operation in CB, it's always recommended to create an index based on the sorting fields. Also, if the index is built in ascending order, then it can't be used for descending ordering and vice versa. Your best option with CB is to create all the possible indices with asc & desc order if feasible.

I'd also recommend that you consider if elasticsearch would be a better fit for your dynamic search use cases.